# NodeJS - Compile markdown into pdf (from a string in memory) and download it on web page

Tags: node.js, markdown, pdf-generation

I'm developing a web page. I want to create an option to generate a .pdf file and allow the user to download it.

Currently I'm using jsPDF but I'm finding it very hard to properly format the document.

I was hoping to find a new way of building it in markdown format, compile it and then download it.

Is there a way that I can do this, in node.js, where say, I have a string in memory (which is the markdown text format), compile that into a pdf and then download it from the page?

I haven't found any package that really does this, if you know, feel free to just let me know which one can achieve this and I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a thing, I recommend building your .pdf file first a HTML file, so you could edit it easily (hardcoded or dynamicaly)
then convert your html file to .pdf file.
there is alot of packages to do this

have a closer look on this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-node

Comment: Thanks. I should've made a more generic question rather than asking specifically for markdown. Building in html is probably still more flexible than what I'm using. Thank you.